# To generate temporary credentials using "AssumeRole" api AWS iOS sdk

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, credentials, temporary

I am newbie to AWS iOS SDK.  I am trying to generate temporary security credentials using **"assumeRole"** api  from iPhone app. I added the AWSSecurityTokenService,AWSRuntime frameworks in my project.  Below is the code.

```
#import <AWSSecurityTokenService/AWSSecurityTokenService.h>
#import <AWSSecurityTokenService/SecurityTokenServiceAssumeRoleRequest.h>
#import <AWSSecurityTokenService/SecurityTokenServiceAssumeRoleResponse.h>
#import <AWSSecurityTokenService/AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    TSC = [[AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient alloc]init];
    request = [[SecurityTokenServiceAssumeRoleRequest alloc]init];
    request.roleArn = @"arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/test";
    request.roleSessionName = @"Bob";
    request.policy = @"None";
    request.durationSeconds=[NSNumber numberWithInt:3600];
    request.externalId=@"abc";

    //[self assumeRole:request];
    @try {
        response =  [TSC assumeRole:request];
        NSLog(@"%@ is response",response);
    }
    @catch (AmazonClientException *exception) {
        NSLog(@" \n\n\nexception %@ \n\n\n", exception);
    }
    @finally {
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }    
}
```

I got the below error message and exception.  Any help would be appreciated.

**objc[1938]: Class AXEmojiUtilities is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities and /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libAXSpeechManager.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2013-01-17 17:16:51.807 AssumeRoleTest[1938:3207] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)
2013-01-17 17:16:51.810 AssumeRoleTest[1938:c07]

exception AmazonServiceException { RequestId:(null), ErrorCode:(null), Message:Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “sts.amazonaws.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0xa381cb0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://sts.amazonaws.com/, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://sts.amazonaws.com/, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “sts.amazonaws.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSUnderlyingError=0x8a64a70 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “sts.amazonaws.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=} }**

1. One more question. How to give the policy details in request? I mean directly can i paste the json format?

   {
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
           "s3:Put*",
           "s3:Get*"
         ],
         "Resource": [
           "*"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  I'll try to address your questions/issues one at a time.

1. It is important to understand that the `AssumeRoleRequest` is a signed request and does require that your `AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient` be initialized with credentials.  You may want to consider using `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest` instead.  We have [a sample](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/iOS/4617974389850313) that shows how to use web identity federation.
2. Setting policy to "None" will likely result in an error.  You should either supply the JSON of the policy you want to supply or nil.  This policy must be a subset of the permissions set on the role you are assuming.
3. The SSL error you are receiving would seem to imply that you are either getting bad DNS results or may be behind some kind of proxy.  Do other AWS services give you similar results?

Finally, you should only need the following import lines in your code:

```
#import <AWSRuntime/AWSRuntime.h>
#import <AWSSecurityTokenService/AWSSecurityTokenService.h>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will check the SSL error.I am getting one more error also.  I have posted the error in next comment.

Comment: objc[519]: Class AXEmojiUtilities is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccessibilityUtilities.framework/AccessibilityUtilities and /Applications/Xcode5-DP.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libAXSpeechManager.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Comment: Can you please give a sample for "AssumeRole" API?

Comment: I fixed this problem. The problem is we cannot use Emoji keyboard in Simulator. In device the above error message ( i.e..Class AXEmojiUtilities is implemented in....) is not coming.

Comment: Other AWS services are working fine. AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" withSecretKey:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"];
      @try {
        [s3 createBucket:[[S3CreateBucketRequest alloc] initWithName:@"myiosbuckets"]];
        S3PutObjectRequest *put = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:self.fileName inBucket:@"myiosbuckets"];
        put.contentType = @"video/mp4";
        put.cannedACL   = [S3CannedACL publicRead];
        put.data        = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.movieurl];
        [s3 putObject:put];

Comment: Can you explain why you want to use AssumeRole?  The value of AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity is that you do not need existing credentials to make the request.

Comment: I decide to go with AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity :)